# Spatial domain to frequency domain

Tags: filter, spatial, frequency

I know about Fourier Transforms, but I don't know how to apply it here, and I think that is over the top. I gave my ideas of the responses, but I really don't know what I'm looking for...

1. Supposed that you form a low-pass spatial filter h(x,y) that averages all the eight immediate neighbors of a pixel (x,y) but excludes itself.

   a. Find the equivalent frequency domain filter H(u,v):

My answer is to (a):

```
1/8*H(u-1, v-1) +  1/8*H(u-1, v) + 1/8*H(u-1, v+1) +
1/8*H(u,   v-1) +      0         + 1/8*H(u,   v+1) + 
1/8*H(u+1, v-1) +  1/8*H(u+1, v) + 1/8*H(u-1, v-1)
```

is this the frequency domain?

b.  Show that your result is again a low-pass filter. 
does this have to do with the coefficients being positive?

Comment: Your answer to a is wrong -- an *equivalent* filter in the frequency domain is not the *same* filter acting on frequency components, it is one that has an equivalent effect on the signal. Think about the effect of h(x,y) on the frequencies in the image. (There is a clue in the term "low pass".)

Comment: You may also have an error in your expression that becomes clear when formatted for readability.

Comment: walkytalky- so is my answer in the correct format? is it something like a*H(u+s1, v+s2) + ... ? Or is it a graph?

Comment: You are asked to find H(u,v). Look at the format you suggest and consider whether it will do that. (Oblique hint: try googling "recursion". If nothing else it will teach you a very famous nerd joke.)

Comment: alright, i've eliminated that format. is it possible to see an example of an answer to the problem that is completely wrong, but in the correct format? I just don't know what kind of notation i'm going for here, which makes applying my knowledge really hard

Comment: h(x,y) generates a new value at each pixel based on a weighted sum of some surrounding neighbourhood of pixels. What is this kind of operation called? What is the equivalent of that in reciprocal space?

Comment: i think you're getting me on the right track. convolution is happening in the spacial domain, which is multiplication in the frequency domain. 

seems like it would be 1/8th or something, but I'm not sure how to compensate for the empty middle

Comment: Suppose the middle wasn't empty. Would 1/8 be the answer then? If not, why not? (And *please* don't say it would be 1/9.)

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say the answer is something like this:

H(u,v) = g(u,v) - delta

where g(u,v) is a box blur

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question but a math / signal processing question.
Try to represent your space functions with dirac function.

Then you have to recognise some well known Fourier transform.